# Get page content and execute shortcodes on a page

Tags: shortcode, pages

I would like to get show multiple page's content on one page with shortcodes. If I use `return $html;` the shortcodes not working, if I use `return do_shortcode($html);` the shortcode working, but the content of the page dissapear. What is the working solution?

```
function get_page_func( $atts ){
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => ''
    ), $atts ) );

    $page = get_page_by_title($title);

    $args = array(
        'include' => $page->ID,
    ); 
    $pages = get_pages($args); 

    $html = $pages[0]->post_content;

    return do_shortcode($html);
}

add_shortcode( 'get_page', 'get_page_func' );
```

Comment: your code works as-is for me with a simple test shortcode embedded in the page called by your shortcode. I imagine any shortcode that relies on knowing the context of the current page will fail though.

Comment: My shortcode: http://pastebin.com/d3w2ZYmF

Sorry It was  too long to paste. Update: if i change return to `echo do_shortcode($html)` the shortcode content is on the top of the page.

Comment: shortcodes should always return content, they can't directly print or echo, that's why your nested shortcode is breaking.

Comment: Yes, I read that, but If I use `return do_shortcode($html)` the page render only the shortcode's output, without the content on the page.

Comment: your *other* shortcode needs to return its content.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_page_func( $atts ){
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => ''
    ), $atts ) );

    $page = get_page_by_title($title);

    $args = array(
        'include' => $page->ID,
    ); 
    $pages = get_pages($args); 

    $html = $pages[0]->post_content;

    $html = do_shortcode($html);

    return $html;
}

add_shortcode( 'get_page', 'get_page_func' );
```

---

Use above code. Wherever you require shortcode to be executed just use the following line

echo do_shortcode('get_page');

This will work for PHP page and also work if you use a shortcode in post or page created using dashboard.

Comment: I would recommend adding square brackets around the shortcode name to properly get the shortcode content: `do_shortcode( '[get_page]' )`;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and code below solved it.

> echo do_shortcode($pages[$i]->post_content);

It doesn't work:

> 1. do_shortcode($pages[$i]->post_content);
> 2. echo $pages[$i]->post_content;

Comment: But OP's code is a shortcode handler. That should return content, not echo it.